# Tab key for kendo date picker not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datepicker

I am having a kendo date picker as follows

[image]

When click the any one of the date picker text with mouse, it hovers the value in yellow colour like shown below. Now, if we click “Tab” button the pointer moving to next field without any issues.

[image]

Now, double clicking the above kendo date picker text with mouse the cursor starts to blink instead of hover the value as shown below. Now, if we click on “Tab” button the cursor not moving to next field and It changing the values of date when I click on “Tab”. This kind of strange behaviour happening only in firefox and in all other browsers working fine with no issues.

[image]

Searched a lot and still searching for the solution. Please, help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because of **masked input** which you have used in your date and time pickers.When i got into similar kind of problem i have used `$(this).focus()` in `keyup()` event.

The following code worked for me:

```
$("#dpkr-1, #dpkr-2, #dpkr-3, #dpkr-4").keyup(function () {   

//To focus the same element once the input is completed in masked date picker. 
 if (this.value.indexOf("_") === -1)  
  $(this).focus();          
});
```

and you can implement the same code for time pickers also.

[Reference](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-keep-tab-order-after-a-datepicker-field)